# Deploy ERC20 token first while still developing the main contract?

Tags: erc-20

Would there be any issues if I deploy the ERC20 token first while still developing the main contract that will give utility to the said ERC20 token? Also, on the main contract, how do I reference the deployed ERC20 token, can I just hard code the token address? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Would there be any issues if I deploy the ERC20 token first while still developing the main contract that will give utility to the said ERC20 token?*

**There is no problem.**

*Also, on the main contract, how do I reference the deployed ERC20 token, can I just hard code the token address?*

**You can hard-code the token address, or you can get it as a constructor.**

See the link below for an example.

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/example-on-how-to-use-erc20-token-in-another-contract/1682

Comment: thank you sir. In the example you linked to, the token.address was passed to the TokenReceiver contract during deployment. If I would be deploying the TokenReceiver at a much later time is it okay to pass just a string address like "0x2df.."? Or is this a bad practice?

Comment: There is no problem.